# Не получается склонировать модуль модульного проекта из ветки на gitlab

Tags: java, git, gitlab

У нас есть репозиторий `gitlab`, в котором находится модульный проект, и множество веток. Я хочу синхронизировать свою ветку с ветками других разработчиков и сейчас мне нужно в свою ветку `dev` скопировать ветку `dashboard_dev` другого разработчика. Я работаю с `git` через меню `Intellij IDEA`: выбираю VCS -> Git -> Pull, в меню ставлю галочку рядом с веткой `dashboard_dev` и нажимаю `Pull`. Часть проекта удалось получить, но модуль `dashboard-core`, находящийся в ветке `dashboard-dev`, спуллить не получилось. Сейчас этот модуль есть в удаленной ветке, но отсутствует в локальной.

Почему так получилось? Как можно склонировать этот модуль себе?

Comment: Вам нужно смержить ветки или создать их локальные копии ?

Comment: @Xoxole, я уже разобрался

Comment: Отпишись, как решил

Comment: @Xoxole, модули скачались, но были не видны. Я выполнил mvn install в папках модулей